# What is IC/OC in microcontroller datasheets?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, datasheet

As I was going through STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller datasheet, I came across IC/OC/PWM. What is the meaning of IC/OC?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=IC%2FOC%2FPWM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, you could have Googled this and should have done before asking. If you were stuck at the abbreviations, try looking deeper and following the trail of crumbs into the datasheet to where the meat of the information is instead of just stopping on the front page or else you will be asking everything about everything. You already gleamed it was something about timers from the stuff around it, so go digging into the timer section to find out more.

Beginners have a tendency to stop a little bit too early in a manual when they encounter something unfamiliar rather than digging just a little bit deeper. They don't give themselves enough credit or believe in themselves quite enough. A lot of what sets a beginner apart from a veteran is knowing how to (or having the will) to try and find something out yourself because eventually something will be too specific or there will simply be no one around to ask. Remember that the only reason the manual/datasheet exists is explain things so that information will probably be in there somewhere. Not trying to find the answer at all is different than trying to find it and failing, or finding it but not understanding it.

IC = Input Capture
OC = Output Compare

They are both timers. Input capture measure and pulse (it captures an input). Output Compare produces an output based on comparison to a value.

What you can't Google is the fact that for STM32s, the real information is in the User Reference Manual. Things common amongst the family are collected in here. Things such as information such as peripheral registers and what they do.

The datasheet just has the information specific to individual microcontrollers (things like pinouts which are specific to the package and microcontroller being used). As a result, datasheets for microcontrollers from ST will contain almost nothing about what things are. So if you ever want to know something, it is probably in the User Reference Manual and NOT the datasheet.